# simple jquery css margin not working

Tags: jquery, css

Just a very simple issue but I'm very new to JavaScript.I'm trying to add a `margin-top` property to a `div` using JS on both `document.ready` and `window.resize`, but no luck.

```
function cent() {
    var blockheight = $("#block").height();
    var margintop = (blockheight / -2);
    $block.css("margin-top", margintop);                   
};

$(document).noConflict();
$(document).ready(cent);
$(window).resize(cent);
```

Comment: check your javascript console for errors. i think this: `$block` should not be working. use `$("#block").css(...)`

Comment: Try using this: http://jsfiddle.net/njs2p/

Comment: your right! the $block was left over from an earlier attempt. even with $("#block").css it still isn't working

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/njs2p/1/

Comment: Please check my answer for the updates and see if that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Hey there, I took your most recent jsFiddle and did some changes which is working now, it converts it to half its original height. Take a look and see if that's what you needed.

Sorry, my code didn't save. Here is my jsFiddle update:

I added in `parseInt()` to guarantee that the height result you receive from `.height()` is an Integer able to be parsed in your division, as well as wrapping the inner portion of `$(document)` and `$(window)` with an anonymous function calling `cent();`.

```
function cent() {
    var $block = $("#block"),
        margintop = parseInt($block.height() / -2);
    console.log('called');
    $('#block').css("margin-top", margintop);
};

// $(document).noConflict();
$(document).ready(function(){
    cent();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    cent();
});
```

Change the

```
$block.css("margin-top", margintop);
```

To

```
$('#block').css("margin-top", margintop);
```

Comment: bit of a conflict problem. ive detailed below. any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Few things,

where are you defining the variable `$block`? you need to put the element you want to modify into that variable so...

```
   var $block = $('#block');
```

in your `cent` function before you define block height.

secondly

you need to call your `cent` function after the document is ready.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    cent();
 });
```

same with `resize` ... so overall the code should look like.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   cent();
   $(window).resize(function(){
      cent();
   });
});
```

if you are unclear on how document ready works, I suggest reading the jquery api, its really usefull and user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your syntax is a bit off. Change `$block` to `$('#block')`.

this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Esbsx/) should help you sort things out.

Answer (score 0):

Change the:

```
$block.css("margin-top", margintop);
```

To:

```
$('#block').css("margin-top", margintop);
```

and also change function call method:

```
    $(document).noConflict();

    //on DOM ready
    $(document).ready(function ()  {
       cent();
    });

    //on window resize
    $(window).resize(function ()  {
       cent();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set which unit to go. .height() will return a number, while the css property margin-top needs to know which unit.

```
var margintop = (blockheight / -2) + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Dylan N's code and all was working in jsfiddle but back in my full page, there is some kind of conflict. Ive narrowed it down to the code below. anyone know what the conflict could be?

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function ($j) {

var image_slides = [];

image_slides.push({
    image: 'img/background.jpg'
})


$j.supersized({



    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')

    min_width: 0,
    min_height: 0,
    vertical_center: 1,
    horizontal_center: 1,
    fit_always: 0,
    fit_portrait: 1,
    fit_landscape: 0,
    slides: image_slides,
});
});
```

Comment: This is a completely different question and should be put in to another question and not as an answer to your earlier question. However, try changing var $j to var j and use $(j).supersized.